# Avoid certain characters in NEWID() in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, newid

I have a table with columns `id` and `name`. In the id column, a key generated using `NEWID()` is inserted.

```
SET @myid = NEWID()
SELECT @id = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), @myid), LEN(@myid)-5, LEN(@myid))
```

This could be some randomly generated alphanumeric key, but I want to avoid the letter O and number 0 from this key. A simple replace of O and 0 will not work. Is there any other method to do this?

Comment: *A simple replace of O and 0 will not work* Why

Comment: Without knowing your requirements and constraints it's impossible to say whether or not there is a "better" way to do "this". However, at the very least you can write that a little more clearly (IMO) by replacing your second call to `LEN` with simply `6`.

Comment: why dont you use the type GUID in your id column ?

Comment: You want a string ID which does not contain confusable characters, so you want to exclude `0` and `O`. `O` never appears, so you only need to worry about `0`. Why can't you just replace it with e.g. `H` or `J`? What is the actual requirement?

Comment: If this has something to do with encryption then this is a bad idea for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`NEWID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function produces a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` value AKA a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier).  You have no control over what the value is, nor should it matter.  If you need to control it, than you are using it wrong.  It's not just a randomly-generated string of characters (I would suggest you read about GUID at the link I provided).

The GUID value consists of hexadecimal characters which is 0-9 and A-F.  Therefore, you would never have the letter `O`.

Comment: Correct or not, this seems like more of a comment unless you can provide some alternative solution.

Comment: Correct answer. It is amazingly funny how little the OP bothers to know about what he deals with - assuming an O will ever appear in a GUID.

Comment: @LCIII -- Sometimes there is no alternative solution.  The question is *specifically* about avoiding characters produced by `NEWID()` (the title even states as much).  My answer is to the point.  Either way, I don't feel that my neglecting to provide an alternative solution renders my answer a mere comment.